# Did Fairy Tail go on hiatus again after episode 277 (or episode 102 after the 2014 restart)?

Tags: fairy-tail

After episode 277 (counting from the 2014 restart, around episode 102), there are no listed episodes in list of Fairy Tail episodes [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Fairy_Tail_episodes). It's due to have some new OVA as well, but the anime did not give a clear indication like the last time that it is going to hiatus.

My questions are:

1. Is it on hiatus right after episode 277 (counting from 2014, episode 102)?
2. Did Hiro Mashima gave some indication (like last time) that it will be back and when it will be back?

Comment: March 26, 2016 was when episode 277 aired. that was like 4 days ago and if you look at the time between most episodes a new episode is aired every week.

Comment: what have you said is true but do not give any incite to what i have asked.there is there is a rumor  that Fairy Tail  will stop temporally to gain more gap between manga and anime ,i'm asking is it already happened or can we expect more episodes before that ?

Comment: why is everyone down voting this question ... i mean what is wrong with it ??

Comment: I down voted because there is nothing in your question which leads to any sort of indication that the series could be on hiatus, instead it reads as wild speculation just because Wikipedia may not have been updated. while you mention a rumour in your comment this is not in your question nor is there any citation of this rumour (like where you heard it from)

Comment: But it is on a hiatus and validity of the question is OK but nvm

Comment: a question is evaluated by the question alone, not by any answer that may or may not be given. if that was the case then why do so many very low quality id request which get high quality answers still get down voted while the answer gets up voted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. **Yes, *Fairy Tail* is on hiatus after episode 101**

   > After making its premiere in April 2014, this season is finally **coming to an end** after 101 episodes, with the **final episode** to be released on March 26.
   >
   > <sup>(Emphasis added)</sup>
2. **Hiro Mashima didn't gave clear indication that it will be back or when it will be back**, but fans speculated a 1-year long hiatus just like the previous.

   > The current season of the anime may be nearing its end, but reports suggest that a **new project is in the works**, with the publisher of the manga, Kodansha's Weekly Shōnen Magazine, slated to officially **reveal the rumored project** in its 17th issue of the year on March 23.
   >
   > <sup>http://www.hngn.com/articles/190587/20160319/fairy-tail-anime-reportedly-new-project-store-fans.htm</sup>
   >
   > Kodansha did not hint at what the new project will be, but **this is not the end for the Fairy Tail anime.**  This is most likely a hiatus, similar to the one that was taken in 2013.
   >
   > <sup>http://goboiano.com/news/4176-the-current-fairy-tail-anime-is-ending-on-march-26</sup>
   >
   > They stopped airing the anime in the year 2013 and came back in the year 2014. So majority of fans expect this Hiatus **to be a year long.**
   >
   > <sup>http://www.otakuvines.org/2016/03/fairy-tail-anime.html</sup>

One of the reasons that may have caused it is the fact that the anime is close to the manga and in order to avoid changing the story (see *Fullmetal Alchemist 2003* and *Fullmetal Alchemist: Brotherhood*), they've chose to let the manga go ahead in order to have the original source material.

Comment: the first quote does not add up, there has only been 12 episodes this year and there are well over 101 episodes. please cite where you got that quote from

Comment: Thanks a lot . remember on the last time when it went to hiatus anime gave a notice in the end , but on this time they did not gave a message like that in the end , so i was wondering what was going to happen ..

Comment: It was my pleasure to help you.

@Memor-X http://www.hngn.com/articles/190587/20160319/fairy-tail-anime-reportedly-new-project-store-fans.htm

Here is the source. I put it at point no.2  and I didn't thought that I should put it to no.1 too. My mistake.
And the quote reffers to Fairy Tail 2014 which has 102 episodes.
http://myanimelist.net/anime/22043/Fairy_Tail_2014
I did not take in consideration the original series, that run between 2009 and 2013, which has 175 episodes.

Comment: they are really going to stop after they get a couple of episodes into a new arc?

Comment: @Joe W I never watched Fairly Tail more than a few episodes so I do not really know the action of the anime arc  but I think is better that they stopped the anime and let the manga make some space with the action rather than continuing the anime , unfollowing the manga and ruining a rather good and popular anime series. It will probably start again having more source material to adapt (gained from this break).

Comment: But it still doesn't make sense to going on a break right after they start a new arc. I can see going on a break when you wrap up one arc and before you start on a new one.

Comment: @Joe W It was either a mistake in the production company in the airing schedule or they wanted to do so in order to create a bigger cliffhanger for the fans  (small chances for this to have actually happened). Most likely they realized that they've been running low on source material and decided to stop the anime at the same time as the Winter 2016 anime season ended in order to keep some kind of season airing symmetry so that they wouldn't stop airing in the middle of the Summer 2016 season (for example) and create even more confussion with a sudden and abrupt break.

Comment: Any updates for this?